Regarding proof that QIP$(m, a, b)$ $\subseteq$ QIP$(m+2, 1, 1 - (a-b)^2)$
I am having trouble understanding why additional interaction is required for perfect completeness. The essential idea of the proof in this paper is that, after the original $m$ rounds, the verifier has the register $\mathrm{R}$ with state $|\psi\rangle = \alpha_{\mathrm{acc}}|\psi_{\mathrm{acc}}\rangle + \alpha_{\mathrm{rej}}|\psi_{\mathrm{rej}}\rangle$.
Now, $\alpha_{\mathrm{acc}} = \sqrt{a}$ if the input was a yes-instance, and $\alpha_\mathrm{acc} = \sqrt{b}$ if the input was a no-instance. Also, $\alpha_\mathrm{rej} = \sqrt{1 - \alpha_\mathrm{acc}^2}$. The verifier creates an additional register $\mathrm{B}$ that is in the $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ state depending on whether the original $m$-turn verifier would have accepted after $m$ rounds. So the verifier has the state
$$\alpha_\mathrm{acc}|0\rangle|\psi_\mathrm{acc}\rangle + \alpha_\mathrm{rej}|1\rangle|\psi_\mathrm{rej}\rangle$$
contained in the register $(\mathrm{B}, \mathrm{R})$. Now, in the paper, the verifier creates another register $\mathrm{B'}$ that has the same state as $\mathrm{B}$ (with the same entanglement) and sends the register $(\mathrm{B'}, \mathrm{R})$ to the prover, and the prover performs some unitary $U$ on $(\mathrm{B'}, \mathrm{R})$ and sends it back to the verifier. The verifier then subtracts $\mathrm{B}$ from $\mathrm{B'}$, applies the transformation $T_a$ to $\mathrm{B}$, and then accepts iff the output is 0.
The transformation $T_a$ is defined by the following action on the basis states:
$$
T_a |0\rangle = \sqrt{a}|0\rangle - \sqrt{1-a}|1\rangle,\\
T_a |1\rangle = \sqrt{1-a}|0\rangle + \sqrt{a}|1\rangle
$$
Now, why couldn't the verifier just apply $T_a$ directly to $\mathrm{B}$ (before any additional interaction with the prover) after partial tracing $\mathrm{R}$ out? We'd get
$$
\begin{align*}
T_a\ \mathrm{Tr}_\mathrm{R}(\alpha_\mathrm{acc}|0\rangle|\psi_\mathrm{acc}\rangle + \alpha_\mathrm{rej}|1\rangle|\psi_\mathrm{rej}\rangle) &= T_a(\alpha_\mathrm{acc}|0\rangle+\alpha_\mathrm{rej}|1\rangle) \\
&= (\alpha_\mathrm{acc}\sqrt{a} + \alpha_\mathrm{rej}\sqrt{1-a})|0\rangle + (\dots)|1\rangle
\end{align*}
$$
Measuring in the standard basis will give output 0 with probability
$$
\begin{align*}
p(0) &= (\alpha_\mathrm{acc}\sqrt{a} + \alpha_\mathrm{rej}\sqrt{1-a})^2\\
&= \alpha_\mathrm{acc}^2 a + \alpha_\mathrm{rej}^2 (1-a) + 2(\alpha_\mathrm{acc} \alpha_\mathrm{rej})\sqrt{a(1-a)}
\end{align*} 
$$
If the input was a yes-instance, then we get $p(0) = 1$, and if the input was a no-instance we get $p(0) \le 1 - (a-b)^2$ from the AM-GM inequality.
What am I missing here?

By sending $(B',R)$ to the prover, the verifier is giving the prover an opportunity to disentangle $R$ along with its own memory from $(B,B'),$  which the verifier cannot do on its own in general. In terms of the argument suggested by the question, the problem is the equation after "We'd get..." This is not the way partial tracing works — it's not a pure state that's left after performing this operation in this situation.

This is very embarrassing, I can't believe I thought $\frac{\mathbb{I}}{2}$ was a pure state. Thank you for pointing that out.
